# How to check Apple compatible devices

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, applepay

I have a payment method Apple Pay it is restricted to only Apple Compatible devices. I need to show the Apple Pay Button if only the Apple Compatible devices.

How do I check Apple Compatible devices like Iphone,Ipad,Apple Watch and Mac in checkout html page using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the Applepay is available using the below code. Link to details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web/apple_pay_js_api/checking_for_apple_pay_availability)

```
if (window.ApplePaySession) {
   var merchantIdentifier = 'example.com.store';
   var promise = ApplePaySession.canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard(merchantIdentifier);
   promise.then(function (canMakePayments) {
      if (canMakePayments)
         // Display Apple Pay button here.
}); }
```